# Why using "profile" in grub to optimize boot time doesn't work for me? How do I revert the effect?

Tags: boot, grub2, xubuntu

[image]I want to speed up the boot time, and I followed a [tip](http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/01/how-to-increasespeed-up-ubuntu-booting.html) to:

1. Edit "/etc/default/grub" and change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash profile"`;
2. Run `sudo update-grub2` and boot up the machine;
3. Edit the grub config file again and remove `profile` from `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`;
4. Update grub again and reboot.

But the result was a increase of a boot time of 10 sec according to `dmesg` output!

What went wrong? Why this tip doesn't work for me? How to revert this setting? Where this profile file is saved in Xubuntu? Can I delete this new profile with no problems?

Comment: Are you sure that the`"profile"` is taken out from `grub.cfg`? Please check it

Comment: Which tip did you follow? Afaik the profiling data is by default written to `/proc/profile`, so it won't persist on reboot. If you removed the option, you're back to normal. Besided, collecting profiling data does nothing to speed up the boot process. It's up to you to analyse the data and make optimizations.

Comment: @Nephente Really? I've done a bit of research and found really old (<2010) guides that ask you to do what the OP did, ie just boot once with the profile option and enjoy less bootime. Maybe it's not like that anymore?

Comment: @Nephente, This tip is every where when we search google for how to speed up boot time on xubunu(ubuntu), please i didn't understand how to revert that back to normal, and why this tip doesn't work for me? maybe this tip doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Can you please add a link to the tip you used? Are you sure it's not outdated? As it's described, it's hard to understand since you apply changes and immediately revert them.

Comment: You are right, my bad. The profile option is read by the `readahead` service. Vladimir, which release are you running?

Comment: @Nephente I'm still using xubuntu 13.10, I didn't upgrade to 14.04 or 15.04 because every thing in my machine is running well with no problems and I'm satisfied with this version.

Comment: @A.L the [link] ( http://www.ubuntubuzz.com/2012/01/how-to-increasespeed-up-ubuntu-booting.html) I know this is outdated, but why this doesn't work anymore?

Comment: I'm starting to understand things here... I'm composing an answer, but I'd like you to append the output of `apt-cache policy .?readahead.*` to your question. There is more than one readahead mechanism at play.

Comment: Could you please append this to your question by [editing it](http://askubuntu.com/posts/684877/edit) and not post any output in the comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**One remark at the beginning:** Although you're content with Ubuntu 13.10, I would still highly recommend upgrading to 14.04 LTS. Saucy has reached end-of-life for over a year now, which means you did not receive any updates for it since then - not good security-wise. Also, technically EOL releases are off-topic here.

---

The kernel boot parameter `profile` is a trigger for readahead profiling at boot-time. If it is set a `readahead` daemon will monitor the boot process , look for files that are loaded during boot and write an appropriate list file. This file will be used on the next boot and should cut down boot-time by reducing hard-drive seeks.

There are a few such readahead mechanisms that came and went over the years. Here is my take on them and I hope this to be more or less accurate.

### Original `readahead` (deprecated)

The last version found in the the Ubuntu archives dates back to 2005. You can't install it anymore through the repository. I don't know when it was superseeded, but it must have been sometime before 10.04.

- profile stored in `/etc/readahead/boot`.
- trigger profiling by moving `boot` and booting with kernel parameter `profile`, although [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/readahead/+bug/262311) suggests its an undocumented and developer-only option.

### `readahead` from Fedora

Originally from Fedora and still used there for systems not booting with `systemd`.

- Ubuntu package is `readahead-fedora`. Available through the repository.
- superseeds the original `readahead`
- profiles stored in `/etc/readahead.d/custom.{early,later}`
- profiling triggered by either

  - `touch /readahead_collect` or
  - setting kernel parameter `profile` on boot.
- automatically profiles at least every month
- Superseeded on Ubuntu by `ureadahead`

The original `readahead` and `readahead-fedora` created a list of files needed at boot time. This list would be read at boot in an order that minimizes hard-drive seeks.

### `ureadahead`

This is the default on Ubuntu since - I think - 10.04.

- Pre-installed
- Really creates a page file which is loaded into memory at boot.
- Stored in `/var/lib/ureadahead/pack`. To force profiling at next boot, remove this file.
- Installs `dpkg` triggers, that fire and update the page file whenever something is installed that relates to `init`.

### Ubuntu >= 15.04

`systemd` is the default init system since vivid. It brought its own readahead mechanism. `ureadahead` does not work with `systemd`. But even `systemd-readahead` is now unmaintained and deprecated, since apparently everbody owns a SSD these days... `ureadahead` is used on Vivid when booting with `upstart`.

---

As expected your system has `ureadahead` installed, which doesn't take the `profile` parameter. Why you would experience prolonged boot time after setting profile is not understandable. If you also applied the second hack in the how-to you followed (`CONCURRENCY=...`), this might be the culprit. `upstart` should take care of that on its own.

As said before, to force `ureadahead` to re-profile, remove the `pack` file

```
sudo rm /var/lib/ureadahead/pack
```

and possibly any other `.pack` in that directory. Be sure to login quickly after boot, because `ureadahead` records a bit even after booting has finished. This way it will hopefully also include the unity shell or whatever you're using.

If you want a really good grasp on what is taking how long to start, take a look at [bootchart](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BootCharting). It generates a graphical representation of the boot process.

Comment: I will do your recomendations, thanks for the remarks.